# How to insert emoij into mysql database with asp classic?

Tags: mysql, emoji

I'm trying to insert an emoji to my MySQL database with a querystring and I don´t know what Im doing wrong?

I have a MySQL database that is set to utf8mb4 and I can insert and emoji to a table with the Mysqlworkbench and it shows as a real emoji. So the database is working as it should. And if I just try to show that on a .asp page then I shows an emoji as it should.
I have set the database, table, and column to be utf8mb4_general_ci, is this right?

And my db connection (koppling.asp):

```
strConn = "driver={MySQL ODBC 5.2 Unicode Driver};server=localhost;uid=xxx;pwd=xxx;database=emojtest;option=3;charset=utf8mb4;" 
set conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.Open strConn
```

To my insertemoji.asp page I'm sending the querystring/variable like this.

```
www.somepage.se/emojitest/insertemoji.asp?text=
```

And my insertemoji.asp looks like this.

```
<!--#include file="koppling.asp" -->
<% 
Response.charset="utf-8"

thetext = request.querystring("text")   


sql= "INSERT INTO news (text) VALUES ('"&thetext&"');"
conn.Execute (sql)
response.write thetext (this is showing ðŸ˜œðŸ˜€ðŸ˜ŠðŸ˜ƒ)
%>
```

But the emoji is not stored as an emoji, only like this `ðŸ˜œðŸ˜€ðŸ˜ŠðŸ˜ƒ` and if it was encoded right it would be something like this I think \xF0\x9F\x98\x82

So what am I missing? Where do I go wrong?

If it should be stored like \xF0\x9F\x98\x82, how do I then convert/encode it to a real emoji when I display it on my .asp page?

How is an emoji suppose to be stored in the DB?

1. Should it be like a visible real emoji?
2. Or like this ðŸ˜œðŸ˜€ðŸ˜ŠðŸ˜ƒ
3. Or like this \xF0\x9F\x98\x82

---

## Solved

I finally figured out the problem, I used the MySQL ODBC 5.2 Unicode Driver and when I changed to MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver it worked!

Comment: Is this embedded in a HTML page? Does the HTML page have `<meta charset="utf8" />` ?

Comment: Its an .asp page and I set Response.charset="utf8mb4" in it.

Comment: Are you opening your .asp page in a browser? Then it's still a HTML file. And `utf8mb4` is a mysql-specific character set. Browsers don't understand it. Add the meta tag

Comment: So it should be Response.charset="utf8"? I thought that I needed to have it as utf8mb4? Have to go out, will be back in an hour. Thanks Evert

Comment: Evert. If we start with the db. Is my database set up right? Should it be utf8mb4_general_ci on the column or should it be utf8mb4_bin? Should it be general on the db and table and bin on the column?

Answer (score 0):

, when Mojibaked, becomes `ðŸ˜œðŸ˜€ðŸ˜ŠðŸ˜ƒ`.  This because of confusion over the hex `F09F989CF09F9880F09F988AF09F9883`, which is treated as Emoji in utf8mb4, but that gibberish by latin1.

To see what probably went wrong in the code, see [Trouble with UTF-8 characters; what I see is not what I stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored)